# perl - help parsing out number values from many small text files

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a number of files in a common directory (/home/test) with a common name:

```
ABC_1_20110508.out    
ABC_1_20110509.out
ABC_1_20110510.out
..
```

Each text file has one record that looks like this:

```
(count, 553076)
```

I would like to strip out the numbers and just list them out in a file one at a time.

```
553076
1005
7778000
...
```

Can someone show me how to do this using perl?

Comment: This is an interesting question because it mixes two concepts: 1. how to process many small text files. 2. how to extract the number values from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a one-liner to me:

```
$ perl -wne '/(\d+)/ && print "$1\n"' *.out > out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Neat stuff. since I'm streaming out values (numbers). I'm interested in doing a sum. Can we do that too?

Comment: @jdamae You can do it either from the out.txt file, or the one-liner above. `perl -wne '/(\d+)/ && ($i += $1); print qq($i\n);' *.txt` Or if you prefer just to receive the sum from out.txt: `perl -we 'while(<ARGV>) { $i += $_; } print $i' out.txt`

Answer (score 3):

use this regex:

```
/\(\w+, (\d+)\)/
```

you can also use the magic diamond operator to iterate over all of the files at once:

```
while (<>) {
    # extract the number
    /\(\w+, (\d+)\)/;

    # print it out
    print $1, "\n";

}
```

And if your perl script is called `myscript.pl`, the you can call it like this:

```
$ myscript.pl /home/test/ABC_1_*.out
```

Comment: I'm getting a `can't open, no such file..`. Somehow it doesn't like that `/home/test/ABC_1_*.out` when I pass it in as you suggested. I can certainly `ls -l ABC_1_*` without no problems

Comment: @jdamae: maybe the full path is wrong?  try `cd`ing to that directory and using `myscript.pl *`

Comment: Should the RE be "/\(\w+, (\d+)\)/" or "/\(count, (\d+)\)/"? There might be other lines that will match that regular expression like maybe "(average, 232)".

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the `<>` operator. When invoking a perl program without arguments, `<>` acts just like `<STDIN>`. If you call it arguments, `<>` will give you the contents of every file in `@ARGV` without you having to manually manage the filehandles.

Ex: `./your_script.pl /home/test/ABC_1_????????.out` or `cat /home/test/ABC_1_????????.out | ./your_script.pl`. These would have the same effect.